# Stretch tab.Panel tab to vertically fit "center border"

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've got a border layout viewport with north, center and south. North and south are ok (toolbar and statusbar). Center is tab.Panel and it's properly stretched to fit width, but not height. First tab of tab.Panel is a simple panel and layout is set to 'fit'.

If I explicitly set height in tabPanel's contents, then it's ok. Without height property child panel is not stretched to height. What's wrong?

This is the code of parent Viewport with the tab.Panel in center:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
                region: 'north',
                buttonAlign: 'center',
                layout: { pack: 'center'},
                items: [ {
                    scale: 'large',
                    text: 'Customers',
                    iconCls: 'ico-customers',
                    iconAlign: 'top'
                }]
            }),
            Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                region: 'center',
                deferredRender: false,
                activeTab: 0,
                plain: true,
                items: [{
                    title: 'Customers',
                    itemId: 'customers',
                    autoScroll: true,
                    items: [
                        {
                            layout: 'fit',
                            title: 'bla',
                            html: 'Something',
                            height: 300
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    title: 'Other',
                    layout: 'fit'
                }],
            }),
            {
                region:  'south',
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Status'
            }

        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, I was misplacing layout:'fit'. Should've placed it under tabPanel's tab, not items of tab.